# Lower Bound on Dirchlet Kernel

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

I suspect this is pretty easy, but I'm not seeing it. In [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel), they show a computation of how to put a lower bound on the dirchlet kernel:
[image]

How do they get from the second to third line? I know the absolute values move out. My guess of the change of variables $s \rightarrow \frac{s-k\pi}{(k+1)\pi}$, but this isn't quite working for me.

Comment: Simply because $\dfrac 1s \ge \dfrac{1}{(k+1)\pi} $ for $k \pi \le s \le (k+1)\pi$.

Comment: @MartinR o my, feel free to add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has  $\frac 1s \ge \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi} $ for $k \pi \le s \le (k+1)\pi$, so that
$$
 \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin(s)|}{s} \, ds \ge  \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin(s)|}{(k+1) \pi} \, ds 
$$
for each $k$. Then the triangle inequality is applied.